# How to calculate the bounds of a square within a circle with known radius?

Tags: geometry

Given these information:

[image: Graphical representation of the shapes]

- Top-left coordinates of the green square, `(0, 0)`
- Center coordinates, `(x, y)`
- Length of the green square, `L`
- Radius of the blue circle, `r` (which basically just `L / 2`)

Is there a way to calculate the bounds (top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left) coordinates of the red square?

Comment: So $l = 2x = 2y$? Or did I not understand your question correctly?

Comment: Correct, @DaanMichiels.

Comment: If it is a rectangle not, because you can change the sides, but if it is a square  then it is determined. Besides, what is length? the perimeter or the side?

Comment: It is a square.. Sorry I've mistakenly stated it as a rectangle. I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following picture.

[image: Useful line segments indicated]

Line segment $a$ has length $\frac{L}2$. Therefore, line segment $b$ also has length $\frac{L}2$ (they are both radii of the blue circle).
Therefore, in the triangle $bcd$ we see that $c$ and $d$ both have length $\frac{L}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Now the center has coordinates $\left(\frac{L}2, \frac{L}2\right)$.
This means that the corner coordinates are $\left( \frac{L}2 \pm \frac{L}{2\sqrt{2}}, \frac{L}2 \pm \frac{L}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

Comment: Your visualization really helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The circle has a radius of $x$, which is also half the diagonal of the red square. So the red square has a side length of $2x/\sqrt{2}=L/\sqrt{2}$. That should be sufficient information to caclulate your *bounds*.

> The $x$- and $y$-coordinates of the corner points are both $x\pm x/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The top-left corner of the red square is a distance $L/2$ from the centre of the circle which is at $(-L/2,-L/2)$. Thus the top-left corner has coordinates $(a,a)$ which satisfy

$$||(a,a)-(-L/2,-L/2)||=||(a+L/2,a+L/2)||=\frac{L}{2}$$

where $||\cdot||$ denotes the Euclidean distance.

Thus we need $$\left(a+\frac{L}{2}\right)^2+\left(a+\frac{L}{2}\right)^2=2\left(a+\frac{L}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)^2$$

so that  $$a=\left(1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)L.$$